# Como hago para dejar quieto un boton en css, sin cambiar de resolucion siempre queda ahi?

Tags: html, css

Quiero dejar un botón centrado en el lugar, pero cuando achico o cambio de resolución se va a otro lado:

```css
.positionbtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 44%;
    left: 46%;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbtn positionbtn">
    <button class="topbtn__btn"><a href="pages/contacto.html">CLICK AQUI</a></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El posicionamiento absoluto se usa para poner algo en un lugar especifico y que esté no se mueva así cambie la resolución de la pantalla pero no para centrar; en tu caso si observas tu pagina desde una pantalla con una resolución de 320px, 576px o 768px el botón siempre se mostrara en sentido de izquierda a derecha a partir del 46% y de arriba hacia abajo a partir del 44%, si quieres centrar el botón usa `text-aling: center;` y con padding-top o margin-top le daría el espaciado.

Saludos

```css
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
/*  */
.propuesta {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

/*  */
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 0.625rem 1.875rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color .10s ease-in-out, background-color .10s ease-in-out, border-color .10s ease-in-out, box-shadow .10s ease-in-out;
}
.btn-primary {
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #0096d6;
    background-color: #378ad3;
}
.btn-primary:hover {
    color: #ffffff; 
    border-color: #0096d6;
    background-color: #0096d6;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es" xml:lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
        <title>Plantilla de pagina</title>
        <meta name="description" content=""/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/www.min.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/template.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <main style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
            <div class="container" style="max-width: 1200px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="propuesta">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="">Texto aqui
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, sin embargo, te sugiero agregar un [mcve] a tu respuesta, ya que permite ver el resultado de tu propuesta. Saludos